# Basic terminal commands not working such as /sudo,/ping,/ls

Tags: command-line

Here's the terminal output

```
cat@cat-B460M-DS3H-AC-Y1:~$ /ping
bash: /ping: No such file or directory
```

```
cat@cat-B460M-DS3H-AC-Y1:~$ /hep
bash: /hep: No such file or directory
```

```
cat@cat-B460M-DS3H-AC-Y1:~$ /help
bash: /help: No such file or directory
```

```
cat@cat-B460M-DS3H-AC-Y1:~$ /sudo
bash: /sudo: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

Enter them without the leading "/". You're on the command line, not the console of your favourite game ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Remove "/" from commands, You entering wrong commands.**

Original commands are :

```
sudo
ping 
ls
```

Comment: whoops minecraft brain kicked in!